# Microsoft Authentication Signout using firebase in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

When I sign out if Firebase in the flutter application the Microsoft account still stays signed-in

I know that the reason for this is that Firebase only signs me out of Firebase but not Microsoft , For Google I can use `googleSignIn.signOut();` to get the expected result but I cant find something similar for Microsoft. If there isn't, is there another way to do this? I tried going through the MSAL documentation but I couldn't find something that works with firebase

Here is my current sign out function

```
signOut() async {
    try {
      String providerId =
          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.providerData[0].providerId ?? "";
      switch (providerId) {
        case 'password':
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
          break;
        case 'google.com':
          final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
          await googleSignIn.signOut();
          break;
        case 'microsoft.com':
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
          break;
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      devtools.log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/azure_ad_authentication/latest/azure_ad_authentication/AzureAdAuthentication/logout.html?

Comment: I want to try to Stick to using firebase as we use firebase auth for our other auth providers.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54237364 and managed to logout from the browser session.